# want to use left join and count

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

here's the request :

```
select offers.*,
       count(*)
from offers left join products on (products.offerId=offers.id)
group by offers.id order by offers.id desc;
```

I want to obtain all offers, even the ones without products inside.
This part works fine.

The question I have is with the `count(*)` part of the requests. I expect `0` when there are no products in the offer. But I get `1`. I understand this may be the line itself (in the `offers` table). I've tried count(products.*) but I get a mysql error... How to proceed ?

Stan

Comment: You need to count a single field in the "right" table, `products.offerId` would seem to be a good fit.

Comment: - Thx that'll do the trick indeed -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) said :

I need to count a single field in the "right" table, `products.offerId` would seem to be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Make nested select

Select *, (select count(*) from products p where p.offerid = o.id) as countofoffers
From offers o